# config-device-connection failing because of other device

Tags: iot-devkit

So I'm trying to execute 'task config-device-connection' from visual studio code.

It starts to execute but then I get an error that the connection is refused with 192.168.1.77:443. But that's not the correct IP adress.

192.168.1.77 is a linux vm that i cannot shutdown.
192.168.1.94 is the ip of the MXCHIP.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you provide the detailed logs displayed in the console window in VS code?

Answer (score 0):

please try the IoT Device Workbench extension for VS Code for the MXCHIP developing.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.vscode-iot-workbench